# set cookie when product is removed from cart and query this cookie

Tags: php, cookies, woocommerce

I'm using this code to add an product to cart. It is permanently there because this code adds it immediately if it's not in cart. 
What I want is that the user has the option to remove it from cart. So it should set some cookie when the user removes it. But how to set a cookie and how to ask if the cookie exists? The cookie can be set forever. So that the user never gets the product automatically again in cart once he deselect it.

```
function add_product_to_cart() {

if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    $product_id = 123; // Product ID to auto-add
    $variation_id = 124; // Set to 0 if no variation

    if ( empty( $product_id ) || ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get WC Cart
    $cart = WC()->cart;

    // Get WC Cart items
    $cart_items = $cart->get_cart();

    // Check if product is already in cart
    if ( 0 < count( $cart_items ) ) {
        foreach ( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];

            // Product is already in cart, bail
            if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id ) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add product to cart
    $cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, $variation_id );

    // Calculate totals
    $cart->calculate_totals();

    // Save cart to session
    $cart->set_session();

    // Maybe set cart cookies
    $cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();
   }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
```